# Changing subviews frames dynamically in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, subview, cgrectmake

I have a view whose subviews' frames I need to be dynamically change in response to user actions. When the view is loaded, I initialize its subviews like this:

```
if (self.firstSubview == nil) {
    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstSubView" owner:self options:nil];
    for (UIView *view in views) {
        self.firstSubview = view;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.firstSubview];
```

Once initialized, when I want to modify the subview's frame, I do something like this:

```
self.firstSubview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.firstSubview.frame.size.width, 200);
```

What I want to do is to adjust the subview's Y coordinate and its height when a user taps a button, and take the subview's original frame back when the user taps the button again. However, I find that sometimes this doesn't work, Y coordinate and height seem to not be set always as I say in `CGRectMake` function. It looks like the function not always takes absolute values, and it depends on the last frame's values instead... I mean, it looks like not always the frame takes the Y = 80 coordinate after this function call.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this works: in the views' `nib` file, I have set top and bottom bars in its `Simulated Metrics`, so the view's height should be the remaining space between those bars and the (0,0) coordinate should be the top left corner below the top bar, right? Is there something I'm missing? Should I re-initialize and add the subview again each time I want to change its frame? Or there is anything else I should do to apply frame's changes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No you should not reinitialize your subview at each time ? Do you use a nib file for your subview as well ? Does it also contains simulated metrics ?

Comment: Yes, I have my subview in another `nib` file that doesn't have simulated metrics set...

Answer (score 0):

The for-in loop you posted will set each element from the array views in order into the self.firstSubview property, so that after the loop self.firstSubview will have the *last* one. If this is really what you want, then here is a simpler way:

```
if (views.count > 0)
    self.firstSubview = views.lastObject;
```

Or perhaps:

```
for (id element in views)
{
    if ([element isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
    {
        self.firstSubview = element;
        break;
    }
}
```